# Does restoring windows 8 pc to factory settings delete info off D drive too?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive

Can I move my big important files to the D drive on my Windows 8 PC so that I can restore my PC to factory settings without losing my files? Or does system restore automatically clear your D drive too? How do I keep the D drive from being restored to factory settings (though it is that because I haven't made any changed to it).

Comment: Factory settings in bios?

Comment: Which refresh are you referring to? Windows 8 allows you to do a refresh without affecting your files, as well as a more complete restore

Comment: Regardless of any other answers it is always good practice to have a backup of important files on an external (preferably offsite) drive ...

Comment: I want to do a complete restore to factory settings using the assistant wizard thing. I got a great new all-in-one PC for Christmas and I wanted to take advantage of its superior hardware so I installed a lot of free new hobby stuff that was supposed to be great, but the main components didn't work which made ALL of those programs and files useless. I want to get rid of all the excess C++ files and hidden folders and so on that are still here even though I've deleted and uninstalled everything. I don't want to use flash drives anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your PC.
Some PC clears all drive but some PC not.

It's better that you backup from PC to an external HDD, then do factory setting.

Answer (score 0):

In windows,there are two option available (i) Refresh (ii) Reset.

If you use the Refresh,it would remove all the desktop application but it would keep the personalised files and modem app .

If you use reset,it would remove all files and apps you have installed and it would look same as that of new installation.

In both refresh and reset,Format of OS would take place but in refresh there wont be any loss of file.If you are doing reset,the files you have created would be deleted.